# Binding Button Enable Property to Text Property of Multiple TextBox WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I am trying to **enable a button** only if text is present in **two text boxes** in a **WinForm Application**.

My Question is - 
Can I achieve this using Data Binding? 
If so how?

**Edit**

Please give reasons for downvote.

Comment: @Yuriy: its not a duplicate of the link you mentioned, as my problem deals with binding a property with two text boxes. Also I am trying to achieve this in WinForms not in WPF

Comment: There are not binding properties available in WindowsForm so there is not out of the box solution available for this.  TextBox.TextChanged event is the one which can help you here.. Or you can think of having some custom solution involving classes and delegates and events.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: look again. Winforms certainly does have a binding API. That's why every `Control` has a `DataBindings` property.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: Please look at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding

Comment: Did you try any of the approaches mentioned in the link?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: I am not able to understand how to do it.

Comment: That's exactly you need to do. Even if someone share the fully working solution you won't be able to understand that too. Then what's the point? You should start learning from that link and start with a simple implementation and then move towards achieving what you explained in this question. Not showing any efforts of solving the issue is the main reason you get downvotes on the question. And there are already two votes for closure of the question. Better you put some efforts and come back with the specific issue you face while implementing the solution using the approach mentioned in link.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: I know how to bind a particular control property to another control property or a class property. But what I dont know is how to bind a control property to the combination of two control properties. I have read the article and did lot of research too since past two days. Asking question in Stackoverflow in my last resort. Please read my question carefully. Initially you commented about `DataBinding` properties were not available in WinForm fell on the face.

Comment: When you are happy with one of either solution please mark it as your accepted answer for future visitors to find the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Since OP want's to work with `DataBinding` only here is a solution with the desired technique.

You'll need to use a [`MultiBinding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx). Add the two `Binding` instances (one for each `TextBox`). Then you'll need to implement an [`IMultiValueConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) that will accept the values produced by the two binding objects and convert them into a single value.

The binding setup would look something like this:

```
var multiBinding = new MultiBinding();
multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Enabled", textBox1, "Text", true));
multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Enabled", textBox2, "Text", true));
multiBinding.Converter = new MyMultiValueConverter();

button1.DataBindings.Add(multiBinding);
```

And the converter implementation would look something like:

```
public class MyMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // perform your conversion here and return the final value
        // so which value both textBoxes need to have that you return `true` so
        // that `button1.Enabled` gets set to `true`
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

That you can use those classes `MultiBinding` and `IMultiValueConverter` you have to add a reference of the `PresentationFramework` lib to your project. Furthermore I suggest you to add:

```
using System.Windows.Data;
```

To shorten your code.

Comment: I am aware that I can achieve this by handling TextChanged Event, I wanted to achieve this using DataBinding

Comment: I think you might mean DataBinding like in `WPF` right?

Comment: DataBinding is available both in WinForms and WPF. Please have a look https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding

Comment: The basic way to go in `WinForms` is how I showed you, subscribing to `events`. I never saw someone else wanting something different, if you really want thought, I'll try it though and show you the results.

Comment: are you able to compile this code? I get an error saying "Binding does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments"

Comment: @dhirajsuvarna Yes I can compile this code. Don't know what you are doing wrong, but then pick the other solution I posted. It uses `DataBinding` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since I already posted an answer and it's a legit working solution in the way OP desired it I don't edit the question, but rather show in a new question another approach.

You could create a computed property and bind the `button.1.Enabled` property to it. For example, create a `textBoxesCorrect` property that returns the value, and bind `button.1.Enabled` to it. The `textBoxesCorrect` property gets set in the `TextChanged()` events of those `TextBoxes`.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "")  //desired text that the textBoxes shell contain
        MyData.textBox1Correct = true;
    else
        MyData.textBox1Correct = false;
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox2.Text == "")  //desired text that the textBoxes shell contain
        MyData.textBox2Correct = true;
    else
        MyData.textBox2Correct = false;
}

public class MyData
{
    public static bool textBox1Correct { get; set; }
    public static bool textBox2Correct { get; set; }

    public bool textBoxesCorrect
    {
        get
        {
            if (textBox1Correct && textBox2Correct)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

So can still work with your `DataBinding`, but it's an easier solution to implement to work with multiple sources for the binding.